# Java servlets - stop executing and redirect on error

Tags: java, servlets

I have the following bit of code in my java servlet:

```
if(passenger == null){
            response.sendError(400, "The specified passenger does not exist.");
        }
```

The page does redirect to the error page, however, the rest of the servlet code is still executed. How do I redirect and sort of 'break' out of the servlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(passenger == null){
            response.sendError(400, "The specified passenger does not exist.");
    return; //or return null; depending on return type of method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If consumer is external which you don't have control, then you may throw runtime exception which will interrupt further execution of consumer.

```
if(passenger == null){
    response.sendError(400, "The specified passenger does not exist.");
    throw new RuntimeException("The specified passenger does not exist.");
}
```